# Strategies for storing derived data in a normalized relational database

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm writing a web application using Spring and Hibernate which maps a fairly complex domain model of people, groups, posts, attachments, comments, etc into a mysql database. This question stems from trying to optimize queries for comments, but applies to other aspects of the site as well.

To simplify the issue, comments have a many:1 relationship with posts, which have a many:1 relationship with a group. Each group has a base url ({/group_slug}) and each post can be accessed by that url followed by a slash and the post id (/{group_slug}/{post_slug}). The posts have a reference to their parent, and calculate their url in a transient method that asks the parent for its url and appends its slug to the end of it. If a comment wants its url, it asks its parent (the post), which then queries the group and creates the url. It works ok, except for the following performance problem:

On the homepage, I want to show all of the recent comments from each of the users groups in a single list. Beneath each comment should be a link to the post that the comment was written about. It's important that this is a relatively quick query, but with the current model I can't figure out how to do this efficiently. My current hibernate query (jpql) looks like this, for each of the groups the user is a member of:

```
select c from Comment c where c.target.group.id = :groupId and c.dateCreated > :date
```

but then to get each url for the target items (due to hibernate eagerly loading the one:many relationship from the comment to the target and then the target to the group) both the target and group have to be loaded from the database as well, for each comment.

Is there a better way to organize this query, or a redesign of the domain model so that I don't have to load so much data every time? If not, what are the cons of de-normalizing the database and storing the url of the comment's parent with it in the database every time a new comment is created? None of the entities change urls frequently, but it is possible for the slug of a post to change. I could handle that situation by looping through all of the associated comments on any slug change and updating the url, but it still seems against best practices.

Comment: Generating an url in your domain object doesn't seem like best practice to me. I don't know what frontend you use, but generating url's should happen there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could eager load it in the query to prevent the SELECT N+1 from happening

```
select c from Comment c join fetch c.target t join fetch t.group g where g.id = :groupId and c.dateCreated > :date
```